# Функция fseek()

Tags: c

Не могу понять принцип работы функции `fseek` в *С*. Допустим, сначала открываем текстовый файл для чтения: `fp=fopen(...)`. Это приводит к тому, что создается указатель на структуру `FILE`, содержимое полей `_base` и `_prt` при этом `NULL`. Далее пытаемся прочесть несколько символов `ch=getc(fp)`, ... Часть файла заносится в буфер, адрес которого записывается в `_base`, а позиционирование по файлу осуществляется по указателю `_ptr`. Казалось, что когда мы хотим получить доступ к определенному байту, `fseek` просто корректирует значение `_ptr`. Но как я понял, получается, что `fseek` просто заново записывает файл в буфер уже начиная с указанного в аргументах места. Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: Вам не нужно знать детали реализации `fseek`. Достаточно понимания того, что она ставит файловый указатель на указанное смещение (с учётом преобразований переводов строк в случае текстового файла). И все дальнейшие операции чтения/записи будут происходить с этой позиции. А как именно она это делает - уже зависит от реализации, которых может быть сколько угодно, и понимание как работает одна из них ничего вам не даёт (на данном этапе, по крайней мере), кроме лишней головной боли.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> когда мы хотим получить доступ к определенному байту, fseek просто
>   корректирует значение _ptr.

Новая позиция в файле может находиться за пределами буфера, причём в обе стороны. В вашей реализации `fseek()` решили, что нерационально проверять граничные условия, а проще сразу

> fseek просто заново записывает файл в буфер уже начиная с указанного в
>   аргументах места.

Но на самом деле это не имеет значения. Потому что реализаций `fseek()` может быть (и есть) много, как и вариантов структуры `FILE`. И что актуально для одной реализации/одного варианты структуры, не имеет смысла для других. Например, "моя" `FILE` (в смысле на моей ОС и в моём компиляторе) выглядит так:

```
struct _IO_FILE {
    int _flags;            /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
    #define _IO_file_flags _flags

    /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
    /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
    char* _IO_read_ptr;    /* Current read pointer */
    char* _IO_read_end;    /* End of get area. */
    char* _IO_read_base;   /* Start of putback+get area. */
    char* _IO_write_base;  /* Start of put area. */
    char* _IO_write_ptr;   /* Current put pointer. */
    char* _IO_write_end;   /* End of put area. */
    char* _IO_buf_base;    /* Start of reserve area. */
    char* _IO_buf_end;     /* End of reserve area. */
    /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
    char *_IO_save_base;   /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
    char *_IO_backup_base; /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
    char *_IO_save_end;    /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

    struct _IO_marker *_markers;
    struct _IO_FILE *_chain;
    int _fileno;

    #if 0
        int _blksize;
    #else
        int _flags2;
    #endif
    _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

    #define __HAVE_COLUMN  /* temporary */
    /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
    unsigned short _cur_column;
    signed char _vtable_offset;
    char _shortbuf[1];

    /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */
    _IO_lock_t *_lock;
    #ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

Немного отличается от пары `_base`/`_ptr`?

Comment: благодарствую за ответ)

Comment: М-м-м ... личная ОС и компилятор :)